# Time Complexity of array operation in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, time-complexity

Is the time complexity to insert an element to a certain index in an empty array is `O(1)`?

For example:

```js
let array = [];
array[5] = 5;
```

Since I want to insert element from the end of array to the front, using `unshift` method would cause `O(n)` in each operation. I wonder if the above operation will be better than the `unshift` method.

Thanks!

Comment: Easy way to find out: Time this for various values of *N*. Do powers of 10, like 1, 10, 100, ... 1e9 etc.

Comment: Time complexity of a direct assignment calls an internal setter and = O(1) while using unshift TC is at a minimum O(n * 2). Calling `unshift` is the first operation that internally calls  the very same internal setter for each of the `n` elements to add.

Comment: @user15178767 if your are really interested in how these things work, then here's a link to the **V8** implementation of the JS [Array.prototype.unshift](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/5d67f90e0f9b76f4e98488126d7658e9228c332f/src/builtins/builtins-array.cc#L603). From this you can be sure to have exact info about the **bigO notation** scale of the operation.

Comment: Would be nice to get a source on @RandyCasburn's claim but it seems correct. As a common sense test you could try doing `array[4294967295] = 1` and see that it's instant. Contrast this with unshift: `array = new Array(4294967294)` 
 then `array.unshift(1)` which hangs for a long time (~60 seconds on M2 Max mac in Node shell). 4294967295 is the maximum array length. Something else to consider with this question is that it's theoretically runtime dependent (v8, webkit, etc.), although in practice there may not be a difference.